# What can I do to make this MySQL query faster (<1s response)

Tags: mysql, caching, indexing

To explain the context. At work we are running a java application that is using MySQL as a data cache. 
We are running some slow Monte Carlo processes to get some results.
We then insert them into the database for later use, so that we don't need to do the costly Monte Carlo again for the same configuration.

Here is the table create code:

```
CREATE TABLE `cache_lte_perfbe_saved` (
`CNUMZONE` DECIMAL(10,5) NOT NULL,
`IDDATASET` INT(11) NOT NULL,
`CRB` INT(11) NOT NULL,
`CENVIRONMENT` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
`CPROPAGATION` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
`CSECTORCONF` VARCHAR(60) NOT NULL,
`CFREQUENCY` INT(11) NOT NULL,
`CINTERCELLLOAD` INT(11) NOT NULL,
`CNBST` INT(11) NOT NULL,
`CNBBE` INT(11) NOT NULL,
`IDLTECONF` INT(11) NOT NULL,
`CTHROUGHPUT` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
`CTHROUGHPUT_ARITHMETIC` DECIMAL(9,2) NOT NULL,
`CDISTRIB` DECIMAL(12,10) NOT NULL,
`VOLTETRAFFICGB` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
`PID` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`SERVICENAME` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
`VOLTETRAFFICERL` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`IDDATASET`, `CRB`, `CNBST`, `CNBBE`, `IDLTECONF`, `CNUMZONE`, `CENVIRONMENT`, `CPROPAGATION`, `CFREQUENCY`, `CINTERCELLLOAD`, `SERVICENAME`, `PID`, `VOLTETRAFFICGB`, `VOLTETRAFFICERL`, `CSECTORCONF`) USING HASH,
INDEX `PK_noVoltenoSectorConf` (`IDDATASET`, `CRB`, `CENVIRONMENT`, `CPROPAGATION`, `CFREQUENCY`, `CINTERCELLLOAD`, `CNBST`, `CNBBE`, `IDLTECONF`, `PID`) USING HASH,
INDEX `PK_noVoLTE` (`IDDATASET`, `CRB`, `CENVIRONMENT`, `CPROPAGATION`, `CSECTORCONF`, `CFREQUENCY`, `CINTERCELLLOAD`, `CNBST`, `CNBBE`, `IDLTECONF`, `PID`) USING HASH,
INDEX `PK_noVoLTEnoFrequency` (`IDDATASET`, `CRB`, `CENVIRONMENT`, `CPROPAGATION`, `CSECTORCONF`, `CNBST`, `CNBBE`, `PID`, `IDLTECONF`) USING HASH)COLLATE='utf8_general_ci' ENGINE=InnoDB ;
```

Here is one query that is taking around 3seconds:

```
SELECT  *
    FROM  cache_lte_perfbe_saved
    WHERE  IDDATASET = 6
      AND  CRB = 100
      AND  CENVIRONMENT = 'high'
      AND  CPROPAGATION = 'IndDay'
      AND  CFREQUENCY = 1800
      AND  CINTERCELLLOAD = 82.0
      AND  CNBST >= 0
      AND  CNBST <= 0
      AND  CNBBE <= 30
      AND  PID = 1586536071412
      AND  IDLTECONF IN ( 2, 17, 18 )
      AND  VOLTETRAFFICERL = 40.0
    UNION 
 SELECT  *
    FROM  cache_lte_perfbe
    WHERE  IDDATASET = 6
      AND  CRB = 100
      AND  CENVIRONMENT = 'high'
      AND  CPROPAGATION = 'IndDay'
      AND  CFREQUENCY = 2600
      AND  CINTERCELLLOAD = 88.0
      AND  CNBST >= 0
      AND  CNBST <= 0
      AND  CNBBE <= 30
      AND  PID = 1586536071412
      AND  IDLTECONF IN ( 2, 17, 18 )
      AND  VOLTETRAFFICERL = 40.0
    UNION 
 SELECT  *
    FROM  cache_lte_perfbe
    WHERE  IDDATASET = 6
      AND  CRB = 50
      AND  CENVIRONMENT = 'high'
      AND  CPROPAGATION = 'IndDay'
      AND  CFREQUENCY = 800
      AND  CINTERCELLLOAD = 84.0
      AND  CNBST >= 0
      AND  CNBST <= 0
      AND  CNBBE <= 30
      AND  PID = 1586536071412
      AND  IDLTECONF IN ( 2, 17, 18 )
      AND  VOLTETRAFFICERL = 40.0
```

[/code]

Here is the explain result of this query:
[click](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7JoHg.png)

The query returns 3000 rows.

As it stands, we can get to 2 million rows inserted and this will make the query quite slow.
I have multiple indexes since we need to query different stuff depending on the simulation options. Meaning we will not always use all the columns in the primary key, so the index would e useless.

Can you help me optimize this query? I am thinking if I should have a different table for each case or not. Maybe using Mysql as a cache is not a good idea.. Maybe I should try to make this table in memory?

Let me know what you think.
Cheers!

Comment: Your table listed first in the EXPLAIN with a key length of 302 is hindering typical performance AND bloats the three indexes hanging from the table.

Comment: No bloating if all the secondary columns are already in the PK.

Comment: `VOLTETRAFFICERL` = 40.0 looks numeric, yet declared `VARCHAR`.  `CINTERCELLLOAD` has a decimal point, but declared `INT`??

Comment: @RickJames good observation on this traffic, I have turned it into decimal 10,2.

Answer (score 0):

- Rearrange the `PRIMARY KEY` so that these columns come first:  IDDATASET, CRB, CENVIRONMENT, CPROPAGATION, CFREQUENCY, CINTERCELLLOAD, PID, VOLTETRAFFICERL .  It does not matter what order they are in.  (More below)
- Toss any secondary indexes that are more hassle than worth..  Probably you can get rid of all three of them.  (This won't *directly* speed up `SELECT`, but will get `INSERTs` to run faster, hence stay out of the way.)
- If you do have need for those indexes, at lease rearrange the columns to have all the columns tested with `= constant` first.  After that, there is rarely any use for having more than one 'range' column.
- Even if you still want all 3 indexes, it may be better to have only the initial list of columns that is common.  (Show the various `SELECTs/UPDATEs/DELETEs` for further explanation.)
- Note that "HASH" is silently replaced by "Btree".
- Use `UNION ALL` instead of `UNION DISTINCT` (`DISTINCT` is the default, but slower).  (If you are expecting dups, but don't want them, ignore this suggestion.)
- 5.7.3 (10.1) has an optimization for `UNION ALL`; upgrade if needed.
- If the table is so big that it is I/O-bound, shrink the `INTs` (4 bytes each) to smaller datatypes.  And consider using a 1-byte `ENUM` for `CENVIRONMENT`, etc.
- Important!  When comparing a `VARCHAR` to a numeric value, the index cannot be used effectively.  I am thinking especially of `VOLTETRAFFICERL`,  But check the others!

The problem with the order in the PK...

Note the "key_len = 12" in the `EXPLAIN`.  12 = 3*4.  That is, it used the first 3 columns, ignoring the rest, of

```
 PRIMARY KEY (`IDDATASET`, `CRB`, `CNBST`, ...
               ---------    ---    -----
```

`INT` is 4 bytes.  The `WHERE` has

```
    WHERE      IDDATASET = 6
      AND                   CRB = 100
      AND                          CNBST >= 0
               ---------    ---    -----
```

The rest of the columns are not used.  Why?  In many situations, only the first few columns of an index will be used:

- First, any columns that are tested with `=`
- Then, *one* range column.
- After that, the rest of the testing is brute force.

Hence, my suggestion of rearranging the PK.

Caveat:  Rearranging the PK will take a long time; the `ALTER` will have rebuild the table completely (and use a bunch of disk space).

Comment: Dear @RickJames,
Thank you for the detailed advice. I have rearranged the primary key order. 
The explain is now looking like so https://imgur.com/a/tbKNBmV
However there is no visible improvement since the table got bigger (2.5 million) and the query time seems to scale off of it, being at 3.5 seconds

I was thinking that maybe this solution has reached critical mass and we should rethink it. Do you think it is worth it to move this table into memory? I have tested it already and it seems quite fast (1.5s). However there is the point of memory consumption..

Comment: @RaduCristianNeagoe - If you have multiple connections, `MEMORY` might be slower than `InnoDB` because of table locking.  Also, you would need to shrink innodb's buffer_pool, which would subtly slow down other queries.  Have you tackled my other suggestions?

Comment: Hello, ultimately I did not go for the MEMORY engine. I have split my table into two tables, since there were queries that did not use all of the index columns in the order that it was created. VOLTETRAFFICGB and VOLTETRAFFICERL have become VOLTETRAFFIC. One table has lost the FREQUENCY column and the other has lost the CSECTORCONF one, since they were never really queried together. I have added a separate index for VOLTETRAFFIC and now my EXPLAIN's  Extra says : using index condition and the amount of rows is significantly reduced. I am getting 0.1-0.2s queries.
Thank you!